# Is Java's Swing really a "memory hog"?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, memory-management

I frequently hear that Java's Swing toolkit is considered a "memory hog" (such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467657/pure-lightweight-application-in-java/467706#467706)).

Is this...

- **A** due to Swing's architecture;
- **B** inherent in Java's memory management; or
- **C** an unfounded claim that stems from a lack of understanding how memory allocation works (e.g. just because the Task Manager says an application has allocated x MB, it does not actually mean that it is actually using all of it)

I'm trying to find a concrete, objective analysis about Swing's true memory requirements as compared to similar GUI toolkits (not necessarily Java).

Comment: "I hear..." Do you have any references for this statement? Otherwise it seems to me somewhat subjective.

Comment: I don't have any references that confirm or refute any claims as to Swing's memory use, hence I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing uses quite a lot of memory that's true, but i would not qualify it as a "memory hog".

As one reply says, in Swing, every component is painted by itself (no use of the OS original widgets), this is what makes Swing portable across platforn.

The Look'n'Feel concept is, from my viewpoint, very good, but it has of course some disadvantages (memory consumption). But I find this disadvantage largely counter-balanced by the possibility to instantly change the look and feel of an application with just one line of code. There are plainty of 3rd-party look'n'feels out there (some commercial, some open source) that can give some "friendly" look to your application.

Also, memory usage is also originated in the way JDK (until 6 at least) loads (or pre-loads) classes in memory: as far as I could see, at the second you run some Swing API in your code, the whole Swing library gets loaded altogether, even though you may not need to all widgets. That may possibly change in JDK7 (which I haven't tested) and "Jigsaw".

Answer (score 4):

I often use the word "bloated" for Swing to mean something slightly different:

Swing bundles everything it needs with itself, rather than using what's already provided.

What does that mean? It means that anything you use/see with Swing is drawn and entirely handled by Swing. By contrast, SWT actually uses the operating system's windows, so naturally it has less memory usage and less work to do on its own. The "windows" in Swing aren't really "windows", they're just made to *look* like windows. By contrast, SWT uses "real" windows, and lets the OS do a lot of their management.

Comment: Then how come eclipse uses as much RAM as intellij? Visual studio on my computer uses 100 - 200 mb, whereas intellij and eclipse can use 300 - 900, usually it's 500 on the average.

Comment: @paulpaul1076: Maybe because there's more to RAM usage than the GUI?

Comment: like what? Lack of value types in java and all that?

Comment: @paulpaul1076: You *are* a programmer, right? You know that just because two programs look vaguely alike to the user that doesn't mean they work the same way internally? Expecting them to use the same amount of RAM is kinda like expecting Windows and Mac to both use the same amount of RAM...

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with these particular programs, look at netbeans, it also consumes 3-5 times as much ram as VS, look at torrent clients written in java, such as Vuze, it uses 300mb of ram, while bittorrent only uses 20. Also an ide called sharpdevelop usually uses 80-120mb of ram whenever I run it. I've always wondered if it's the java platform, or the way their GUI libraries are written that makes them such a memory hog.

Comment: @paulpaul1076: I cannot find a logical way to compare the memory usage of two IDEs. There is so much work and code that goes into the design and implementation of an IDE that I cannot give you a meaningful comparison. In order to compare the memory usage of two libraries you have to either isolate the library's memory usage somehow and measure that (I don't know how), or write the same program with both and compare the two versions. You can't compare apples and oranges.

Answer (score 2):

Please see attached the test show it to be a draw in many cases:

> #### Conclusion
>
> It is hard to give a rule-of-thumb where SWT would
> outperform Swing, or vice versa. In some environments (e.g., Windows),
> SWT is a winner. In others (Linux, VMware hosting Windows), Swing and
> its redraw optimization outperform SWT significantly. Differences in
> performance are significant: factors of 2 and more are common, in
> either direction.
>
> It is questionable how often Swing's capability of
> suppressing successive redraws is effective. It is very likely that in
> practice this is not a frequent occurence, as repeated update requests
> in a short period of time may be uncommon. In this case, results of
> the Swing Text Field (sync) test should be considered with greater
> credibility than those of the Swing Text Field test, as they
> approximate the resource usage more closely.
>
> Initial expectation
> before performing this benchmark was to find SWT outperform Swing.
> This expectation stemmed from greater responsiveness of SWT-based Java
> applications (e.g., Eclipse IDE) compared to Swing-based applications.
> However, this expectation could not be quantitatively confirmed. It is
> possible that perceived responsiveness is a consequence of smaller
> time required to respond to user interaction, which involves not only
> drawing, but also detecting and responding to the user's action. Also,
> determinism (smaller standard deviation) could result in greater
> perceived responsiveness.

Source: ["SWT Vs. Swing Performance Comparison" by Cosylab d.o.o](https://web.archive.org/web/20150526225341/http://public.cosylab.com/CSS/DOC-SWT_Vs._Swing_Performance_Comparison.pdf)

Comment: Not a real answer to the question, you docus on performance while the OP asked about memory usage (although I admit there can be some impact of the second on the first).

Comment: Your point is well taken the conclusion of the report may not be the best to call out in my answer. But the tables in the report which shows the resources used, and gives the best comparison I have seen.

Comment: This report is quite outdated and doesn't show memory resources consumption. I was also surprised by the poor timing obtained for JTable, for which I wonder how the code was written.